# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in a FOR Loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, replace, character

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main (String [] args){

    String word = "ErFLwWSa$ F?ytWtmVRLWmDj #4STs!@  VRa!12OW";
    String word2 = "GREEN";
    String result ="";
    for(int i = 0; i<=word2.length()-1; ++i){
        result += word.replace(word.charAt(i),word2.charAt(i+1));
    }
}
}
```

Basically what I am trying to accomplish.

Say I have any string `word` I would like to know how many times I can fit the letter in `word2` in `word`, space , numeric and symbols are not counted.

Basically the output should show me something like this.

`ErFLwWSa$ F?ytWtmVRLWmDj #4STs!@  VRa!12OW`

`GREENGRE  E NGREENGREENG   REE    NGR   EE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a string of length 10.

`for(int i=0; i<a.length();i++)` runs from 0 to 9 (10 in total) - Remember, Java arrays are 0-based.

`a.length()` would be 10, `i` will run from 0 to 9 (9 is the maximum integer that is smaller than 10, in the next iteration the for condition won't be satisfied).

When you do: `if(a.charAt(i)==a.charAt(i+1))` you're trying to reach the the element in position 10, thus you're getting the exception.

Comment: I'd rephrase it as 'the element in position 10'.

Comment: Indeed, much better :)

Comment: So basicly tring to read caracter 11 which does not exist ? Now how would counter that ? Add a if statement if I'm at the last cycle of the loop ?

Comment: If you're array is of length 10 then it has indexes from 0 to 9 (So 10 is out of bounds). Yes, the solution you proposed is fine.

Comment: @hayonj: Instead of checking every iteration, I'd just adjust the loop condition... `i < a.length() - 1`

Comment: Right, if you loop until `a.length() - 1` then `i + 1` won't be out of bound.

Comment: You could just itterate from 0-8, so your for would be for(int i=0; i<a.length()-1;i++)

Comment: @MarounMaroun can't you help me on the part ? I'm stuck ... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620465/returning-a-variable-to-a-method-ofrom-within-a-switch-statement)

Comment: @hayonj In what part are you stuck? Can you please post it?